# Format conversion in java using arraylist

Tags: java

I am using one ArrayList which is as follow:
(A,Start,2),(A,End,7),(B,End,3),(C,Start,8),(C,End,4).

I want to convert above ArrayList into below format.
A,(2,7)
B,(0,3)
C,(8,4)

```
public Set<Demand> DemandData(){
    ArrayList<Demand> Demanddata = new ArrayList<Demand>(); 
    Demanddata=LoginDAO.getDemandData();
    Set<Demand> dListUnique = new HashSet<Demand>(Demanddata);
    for(Demand di:dListUnique){
        for(Demand dj:Demanddata){
            if(di.getSeatJRSS().equals(dj.getSeatJRSS())){
                String data = "";
                // I tried here
            }
        }
    }
    return dListUnique;
}
```

Comment: It seems like you rather want a `Map<String,List<Integer>>`.

Comment: Start with creating another class where `demand` will be kept as its name and two integers referring to `start` and `end`. Then iterating over "old" demand, collect "new" ones in `Map` by name, creating new if map doesn't contain provided key or modifiying start/end if a demand already exists.